# Default values for route parameters in REST resources

Tags: 8

The title says it all: is it possible to set a deafult value for a parameter configured in the `uri_paths` of a RestResource? I had a look at the code of `RestResource` and I have a feeling that it is not supported, since `uri_paths` is simply a map; but still, I thought it was worth asking the question :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `ResourceBase` generates a `RoutingCollection` in `ResourceBase::routes()`, which you can then loop through and play around with (see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21rest%21src%21Plugin%21ResourceInterface.php/function/ResourceInterface%3A%3Aroutes/8.2.x).

Let say your `uri_paths` looks like this:

```
uri_paths = {
  "canonical" = "/api/fetch/{some_id}"
}
```

Simply override the method in your own Resource, fetch the `RoutingCollection` from the parent - e.g. `ResourceBase` - and give your parameters a default.

Like so:

```
  public function routes(): RouteCollection {
    $collection = parent::routes();

    // Add a default of NULL for the 'some_id' optional parameter.
    foreach ($collection->all() as $route) {
      $route->addDefaults(['some_id' => NULL]);
    }

    return $collection;
  }
```

The parameter should then get that default value, when it's not provided in the call.

So if your `get()` looks like this:

```
public function get($some_id = NULL): ResourceResponse { .. }
```

The GET-call to `/api/fetch/2` would set `$some_id` to 2, while a GET-call to `/api/fetch` would set `$some_id` to `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to add something to the route, it might be better to override the `getBaseRoute` function of `ResourceBase`, because then you don't have to loop through every route if you only want to add an option to one of them.

```php
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function getBaseRoute($canonical_path, $method): Route {
    $route = parent::getBaseRoute($canonical_path, $method);
    if ($method === 'GET') {
      $route->addDefaults(['some_id' => NULL]);
    }
    return $route;
  }
```